# MSBuild clean operation fails due to missing dependency

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, cruisecontrol.net

I have a visual studio 2010 solution file containing a number of project files. If I clean the solution using `devenv` then the clean completes successfully, however, if I use MSBuild, two of the project files fail to clean due to a missing dependency, `error MSB3395`. If I run Clean a second time, immediately after the failure, the clean completes without errors.

Our build using MSBuild succeeds.

> Task "UnregisterAssembly" (TaskId:204) ...
>
> ...
>
> error MSB3395: Cannot unregister assembly 
>   "C:\Build\Dir\MyFile.dll". Could not load file or 
>   assembly 'MyOtherFile, Version=10.0.0.414,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=266e457ed35afd03' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   [C:\Build\Dir\ProjFolder\MyFileProj.vbproj]

Yes, this assembly is a COM interop assembly and so the build registers the assembly. If I delete the UnmanagedRegistration.cache files associated with the two problem areas then the clean finishes without problems. However, these files are not unregistered and registry fills up with old COM registrations. I am not certain of the impact on future builds either.

I have read the article for VS2008 projects here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2010/12/21/incorrect-solution-build-ordering-when-using-msbuild-exe/
However, I don't think this applies in this case because this build process has been cleaning and building properly for months.

I have also read: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26259422/msbuild-can't-clean-project-with-C-COM-component-dependant-on-other-NET-library.html. I attempted to clean the two different projects before cleaning the solution affected by this, but this too failed. e.g.,

```
msbuild ".\ProjDir\MyProj.csproj" /t:clean /p:configuration=Release /fl /flp:logfile=".\..\LogFiles\msbuildClean.log";verbosity=diagnostic
```

I have tried reverting to a previous SVN revision before the problem began to show but I still get the same error. My build machines are on Virtual Machines, and I even tried reverting the build machine to a snapshot prior to the problem showing up, but still the error would show up.

I have been at this for two weeks now, and my only recourse is to use `devenv` to clean the solution, which is very slow. My only idea at this time is that when using msbuild that dependencies for COM interfaces are not handled correctly for a clean but I have no idea how to fix the problem.

I can reproduce the problem using the VS2010 CMD Prompt. Below is an example cmd line that I use

```
msbuild "A Solution.sln" /t:clean /p:Configuration=Release /fl /flp:logfile=".\..\LogFiles\msbuildClean.log";verbosity=diagnostic
msbuild "A Solution.sln" /t:build /p:Configuration=Release /fl /flp:logFile=".\..\LogFiles\msbuildBuild.log";verbosity=diagnostic
```

Within the vbproj files there are PropertyGroups with a Release configuration condition. All of these include `<RegisterForComInterop>true</RegisterForComInterop>`. If I set this value to false, then the error goes away because there isn't anything to unregister. However, I need the `.tlb` files in order to compile our `vb6` project.

So, are there any problems for me to just set this to false and then use Regasm to register the assemblies post build, and unregister before a clean? Does anyone have any ideas why MSBuild would suddenly have problems with this process when for months the build has run successfully?

Thanks.

### UPDATE

- If I use msbuild to clean the first problem project, this clean works
  successfully.
- The second project however fails to clean properly
- When cleaning the first project, ProjA, it also removes dependent
  files from other projects, ProjB.
- When I clean the second problem project, ProjC, it also has dependencies on  ProjB.dll, and this file is missing.

### QUESTION

- How do I keep MSBuild from removing files required by other projects?

Comment: This is not an interop assembly.  Never ignore the "or one of its dependencies" phrase.  This can go wrong if it cleans files in the wrong order, deleting a dependency before trying to unregister MyFile.dll.  Why this happened is impossible to guess without you providing a detailed build trace.

Comment: No idea what goes wrong, but you might spend (waste) less time settling for a workaround like a pre-clean target which just deletes the projects' outputs manually.

Comment: See also the issue at https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/1230

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I have to go with stijn's answer. 
I never did find the cause - something in the msbuild clean process seems to delete the files required to unregister an assembly. 
I had tried to create a msbuild task to unregister the assemblies first, but that too failed. 
In the end I coded a Powershell script that searched a path for `*.unmanagedregistration.cache` files. I then can determine the .dll file name from the unmanagedregistration.cache file and then once the code runs `regasm /unregister`, it will remove the file.

Answer (score 0):

Just perform the clean as administrator. If using visual studio, open it as administrator and it should perform the clean action.